# Bootstrap gallery 3 Modal Light box and carausel not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-modal

http://www.bootply.com/RBoCXCJtXh

I was looking for snippet for a portfolio gallery section like this  but the carousel seems like its not working when I click the arrows. I am still a beginner in jquery so I am not sure how to customize to the one I am trying to achieve where when I click next it will go to the next slide with the content.

If anyone can help me out I would be grateful!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The carousel is working fine but you are "copying" only 1 image to the modal.

you should change this:

```
var repoCopy = repo.filter("#" + id).clone();
var active = repoCopy.first();
```

whith this:

```
var repoCopy = repo.clone();
var active = repoCopy.filter("#" + id).first();
```

[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/vmateus/eDkaU5Sefz)

Comment: Thanks Vitor! Funny thing is when I am trying this on my local drive offline test the caraousel animation dosent animate but just jumps to the next slide. Which is weird I copied the updated code of yours.